# Protractor tests getting stuck in between while resolving promises when executing in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, promise, protractor

My protractor tests were working perfectly fine yesterday on Chrome Browser.
Today, it started failing consistently at a point where in I resolve a Promise. On debugging further, I found that if I commented this promise statement then it would hang at the next promise resolution statement.

There has been no change in the protractor scripts between yesterday and today. There has been some changes made by the developers in the Angular app under test but not major ones.

Can anyone help me point out what might be going wrong here?

Following is the code snippet. Its hanging at the promise resolution statement template.getTemplatesCount().then :-

```
mainMenu.clickTemplatesMenuOption();

templatePage.getTemplatesCount().then(count => {
  console.log("Count of template card is:-"+count.toString());
  templateCountBeforeInsert = count;

});

templatePage.openCreateTemplatePanel();
createTemplatePage.createTemplateWithoutDocument(templateName);
```

My protractor conf.json looks like this:-

```
 exports.config = {
 allScriptsTimeout: 30000000,
 specs: [
 './e2e/TestPlan/*.ts'
 ],
 capabilities: {
'browserName': 'chrome'
},
directConnect: true,
baseUrl: 'http://10.37.1.86:81/',
getPageTimeout: 120000,
framework: 'jasmine2',
jasmineNodeOpts: {
 showColors: true,
 defaultTimeoutInterval: 120000,
 print: function () { }
 }
```

Following are the versions of Tools I am using:-
Protractor:- 5.1.2
ChromeDriver:- `2.32
Chrome Browser :- 61.x

Comment: I am totally blocked here. Can anyone throw some pointers to get it resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You should be passing a function to your `.then()` block, it should be this:

```
templatePage.getTemplatesCount().then((count) => {
    console.log("Count of template card is:-"+count.toString());
    templateCountBeforeInsert = count;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is add catch() as below:

```
templatePage.getTemplatesCount().then(count => {
  console.log("Count of template card is:-"+count.toString());
  templateCountBeforeInsert = count;
})
.catch(function(err){
  console.log('getTemplatesCount error: ' + err);
});
```

If you get the error log, please check getTemplatesCount() inside.